# development server?

Tags: development

for a project there will be me and one more programmer to develop a web service.

i wonder how the development environment should be like.

cause we need central storage (documents, pictures, business materials etc), file version handling, lamp (testing the web service) etc.

i have never set up an environment for this before and want to have suggestions from experienced people which tools to use for effective collaboration.

what crossed my mind:

```
seperate applications:
- google wave (for communication forth and back, setting up guide lines, other information)
- team viewer (desktop sharing)
- skype (calling)

vps (ubuntu server):
- svn (version tracking)
- ftp (central storage)
- lamp (testing the web service)
- ssh (managing the vps)
```

is this an appropriate programming environment? and regarding the vps, is it best practice to use ONE vps for all tasks listed up there?

all suggestions and feedbacks are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds good, but what you'll definitely need, is some bug tracker (Trac, Bugzilla, ...) An internal Wiki is a good idea, too. I'd use WebDAV with HTTPs (or sftp) instead of ftp though.

About the server: As long as there are no security concerns (different people using different services, or people allowed to access some services from the Web, while others can only be accessed from the LAN, ...) I'd start out with one server. You can always separate the services later. The first thing I would separate, is the test server: This way you can even set up many cloned VPS for multiple test environments.